# NSCalendar compareDate: toDate: toUnitGranularity fails

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar

I created test case to help track some NSDate time zone issues and ran into a problem I didn't know I had. NSCalendar does not return what I expect for equal dates:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSComparisonResult dateWithTimeComparedToStartDate = [calendar compareDate: dateWithTime
                                                                    toDate: startDate
                                                         toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnitDay];
XCTAssertTrue(dateWithTimeComparedToStartDate == NSOrderedSame);
```

The debugger output shows the same dates, but different times:

```
(lldb) po dateWithTime
2017-12-08 03:52:36 +0000

(lldb) po startDate
2017-12-08 06:00:00 +0000

(lldb) p dateWithTimeComparedToStartDate
(NSComparisonResult) $2 = NSOrderedAscending
```

I would expect NSOrderedSame, rather than NSOrderedAscending.

Comment: What is `calendar.locale.timeZone`?

Comment: It was CST, changing it to UTC made it pass. In trying to find a problem, I created a similar problem in my test case. Thanks